# Telegram Bot API missing object

Tags: .net, bots, telegram

is `InlineKeyboardButton` removed in version 13 of nuget telegram bot api?
i used a sample project that was using telegram.bot version 10 and it contains the `InlineKeyboardButton` in the `telegram.bot.types` and it works fine.

but when I use the version 13, i get an error.

any idea ?

this is part of the whole code :

```
            if (message.Text.StartsWith("/inline")) // send inline keyboard
        {
            await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);

            var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                new[] // first row
                {
                    new InlineKeyboardButton("1.1"),
                    new InlineKeyboardButton("1.2"),
                },
                new[] // second row
                {
                    new InlineKeyboardButton("2.1"),
                    new InlineKeyboardButton("2.2"),
                }
            });

            await Task.Delay(500); // simulate longer running task

            await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Choose",
                replyMarkup: keyboard);
        }
```

Comment: please provide your error and a snippet(s) of your code, so you may get a help better.

Comment: @tashakori i added that part . i got the red underline in VS .. and after removing version 13 and adding version 10 reference,the error went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentiond in changelog:
https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

"User and Chat Ids reverted to base types
DateTimes are now in local time zone
Splitedd Keyboardbuttons in InlineKeyboardCallbackButton, InlineKeyboardCallbackGameButton, InlineKeyboardPayButton, InlineKeyboardSwitchCallbackQueryCurrentButton, InlineKeyboardSwitchInlineQueryButton and InlineKeyboardUrlButton"

Note that InlineKeyboardButton is no longer available, use 
InlineKeyboardCallbackButton instead.